# discord oauth2 api call returns "405: Method Not Allowed"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, discord

Im making a website where a user can login with their Discord account.

I'm making an API call that looks like this:

```
https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=791748434310201344&client_secret=superSecretID&redirect_uri=mywebsite%2Fprotocols%2Fadd_discord.php&code=KI5LYgKj7QuO3oBkddXQW6SnJbg17K&scope=identify
```

I was expecting a return like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "6qrZcUqja7812RVdnEKjpzOL4CvHBFG",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 604800,
  "scope": "identify"
}
```

But instead, I got:

```
{"message": "405: Method Not Allowed", "code": 0}
```

I've been looking at the [Discord oauth2 documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) for a while now, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: validate your get values and the query your db to match the values;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're making a `POST` request, other methods (like `GET`) are not allowed.

If you run the snippet below, you can see that with `GET` you're receiving a "method not allowed" error, while with `POST` it's just complaining about the invalid `client_id`:

```js
fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=superSecretID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fadd_discord.php&code=xxx&scope=identify', {
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log({
    method: 'GET',
    res
  }))
  
fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=superSecretID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fadd_discord.php&code=xxx&scope=identify', {
    method: 'POST'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log({
    method: 'POST',
    res
  }))
```